# array inside Request Parameter php

Tags: php, arrays

Can I pass an array inside the request parameter in php

for example

I have an hidden submit form here

```
<form action="" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="myarray" value="' . $arrayofvalues . '">
```

can I then call the correct variable like this?

```
($_REQUEST['arrayofvalues[1]']
($_REQUEST['arrayofvalues[2]']
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just use PHP array syntax in your input name attribute:

```
<input type="hidden" name="myarray[]" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['myarray'][0]; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="myarray[]" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['myarray'][1]; ?>">
```

And in PHP:

```
print_r($_REQUEST['myarray']);
```